# View all item link in Content Query webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part, item-styles

Using Content Query webpart to display item from link list.
I have created template in ItemStyle.xsl stylesheet to change look and feel
but i need last item should be View All item link.Need to show only 9 item(8 item+ view all link)

Comment: used below mentioned condition to solve issue using xsl     test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=8"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following of code to Script Editor web part on the page:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("span[title='YOURWEBPARTITLE']").closest(".ms-webpart-chrome").find("ul").append("<a href='/Lists/YOURLIST/Forms/AllItems.aspx'>All items...</a>")
</script>
```

Where YOURWEBPARTITLE is the title of CQWP.

[Source](http://blog.jussipalo.com/2012/05/sharepoint-append-link-to-bottom-of.html)

Comment: thanks jussi...i have used below mentioned code test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=8"